# Restore database in SQL Server from .bkp file

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

I work in data migration, and we occasionally receive disparate file formats no one in the office has heard of before. Such is the case with a recent project, where the client's previous vendor's system produced a database backup in a `.bkp` format. I've done some Googling and haven't found much besides that it's an old backup file type, and one search result suggesting to just rename the file to a `.bak` and restore it.

I've attempted the latter using the restore database utility in SSMS, but I get the following error:

> Restore of database 'director' failed. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 8.00.2039. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 15.00.2080. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

The link just looks like it goes to Microsoft's homepage... This backup was taken from a funeral arrangement software called Aurora.

I've also just opened it in Notepad, and it looks to be encoded. I can make out some SQL in the text editor but it's mostly garbled.

Are there other available resources? Or is there a way to extract the SQL from this file? I'm using a Windows box in an Amazon workspace that my work set up for me, I'm not sure if that's limiting or if it gives me more flexibility.

EDIT:
Geez, I looked on here but couldn't find anything. Thank you all! Answered in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15729493/9437228

Comment: So your backup file is from a SQL Server **2000** machine, and you're trying to restore it to SQL Server 2019 (v15). That won't fly - you will need to install a previous version of SQL Server (something like 2008 R2) in order to restore the backup from SQL Server 2000, then update the database's compatibility level, do a backup again - and then you might be able to restore that newly created backup onto your SQL Server 2019.

Comment: The error message seems very clear. It's a backup from SQL Server 2000 and it cannot be restored to SQL Server 2019. you'll probably need to restore it to an intermediary server eg 2008, backup and then try restoring that.